# tf.keras.utils.multi_gpu_model does use only one GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have two GPUs available which I want to use both to get maximal throughput during inference. That why I wanted to use multi_gpu_model, it should process half of the batch on one GPU and the other half of the other.

However, only one GPU is used (checking with nvidia-smi).

I could reproduce it with the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import Xception
from tensorflow.keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
import numpy as np

num_samples = 32
height = 224
width = 224
num_classes = 1000

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    model = Xception(weights=None,input_shape=(height, width, 3),classes=num_classes)

# Replicates the model on 2 GPUs.
# This assumes that your machine has 2 available GPUs.
parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2)
parallel_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

# Generate dummy data.
x = np.random.random((num_samples, height, width, 3)).astype(np.float32)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)
dataset = dataset.batch(32)
dataset = dataset.repeat()

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
batch = iterator.get_next()

y = parallel_model(batch)

sess = tf.keras.backend.get_session()
while True:
    try:
        result = sess.run(y)
        print(result.shape)
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        break
```

I expect this to use two GPUs, but it uses only 1. Is this a bug or is this expected behaviour? How to change this example to use multiple GPUs?